# Deploy app with .NET 2.0 SP2 framework packaged

Tags: .net, frameworks, installation

I want to package the .NET 2.0 installer with my .NET app, so which installer do I use for the latest .NET 2.0 SP 2? Assuming the target machine is XP/Vista/7, and assuming it has no .NET framework installed.

1. [Netfx 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=22808) (2006, size 23 MB)
2. [Netfx 2 SP 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=16614) (2007, size 24 MB)
3. [Netfx 2 SP 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=1639) (2009, size 25 MB)

Do I need just the latest SP 2 installer? Or do I need all 3 to be installed in sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or do I need all 3 to be installed in sequence?

No, the service pack versions are complete installers that don't require the previous version of .NET 2 to be present. You can tell from the file size.